# iOS Swift Receive Push Notification When App in Foreground

Tags: ios, push, firebase-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

Here is the code that I have used to receive push Notification when app in foreground

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
     completionHandler([UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert,UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound,UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge])
}
```

But my problem is that my notification contains [NSObject : AnyObject] values. How to receive like background notification

Comment: Do you want to access user info from Notification object?

Comment: @iOS_devloper yes sir

Comment: I am using "notification.request.content.userInfo" to get data. You can print this in above method.

Comment: You can use notification.request.content.userInfo

Comment: @iOS_devloper If it solved the post, you should add that in as the answer (plus a few more details if you have them). Cheers!

Comment: @AL. Thanks! Posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this code in AppDelegate.swift file.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler([UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert,UNNotificationPresentationOptions.sound,UNNotificationPresentationOptions.badge])
}
```

Comment: how to write this in iOS 8.0 @Kavin Kumar Arumugam

Comment: @DilipTiwari there is no changes in above code, it already supports iOS 8.0

Comment: ok so it will show notification in foreground also @Kavin Kumar Arumugam ?

Comment: can you tell me your firebase version @DilipTiwari

Comment: i m receiving in ios 10 but not in ios 8 @Kavin Kumar Arumugam

Comment: can we talk in a group chat @kavin kumar arumugam

Comment: this is my code https://paste.ofcode.org/a3fEwUmYi7bQPYG7WHHgjA @Kavin Kumar Arumugam

Comment: Little busy now will see and update your code by evening @DilipTiwari

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155479/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-kavin-kumar-arumugam).

Answer (score 1):

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

   if (application.applicationState == 0) // active --- forground
    {
       // publish your notification message
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your app won't be able to run any code unless the user open the push notification, push notifications are handled by the OS and your app have no control on them while it's not active or in the background you should take a look https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html

Answer (score 1):

UNNOtification has property  request ([UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest)), you can use that to get user info.

use following to access user info from UNNotification:

```
let userinfo =  notification.request.content.userInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    debugPrint("Received when is visible... :): \(userInfo)")
    

    guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        completionHandler(.failed)
        return
      }
    
    let alert:Dictionary<String,String> = aps["alert"] as! Dictionary<String,String>

    let title:String = alert["title"]!
    let msg:String   = alert["body"]!
    
  
    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    
    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
         
        refreshAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      
    }))


    UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 
}
```